# AstroJs: Is it possible to have multiple returns inside getStaticPaths()?

Tags: javascript, astrojs, dynamic-routing

I am working on a project using AstroJS. The goal is to have a few images, a title, and a description appear on a single page following the dynamic routes method using the getStaticPaths function.

Start with Image library

```
src
  images
    apple
      apple-01.jpg
      apple-02.jpg
      apple-03.jpg
      apple-03.jpg
    banana
      banana-01.jpg
      banana-02.jpg
      banana-03.jpg
      banana-03.jpg
```

And page outcome as expected

```
/page/{path}
------------
    {Title}
    {Description}
    {Image}
    {Image}
    {Image}

------------
```

Fortunately, I've succeeded in getting multiple images onto a single page following [Bryce Russell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75128887/6387458) coding example. However, I am struggling to find a way to include the title and description, despite trying some form of [Data Passing Props](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#getstaticpaths) in combination with [Bryce Russell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75128887/6387458) coding example.

This code below is my 8th attempt, and...

```js
// [page].astro
---
import fg from "fast-glob";

export async function getStaticPaths() {

//Data array for titles and description based on image folder name 
  const labels = [
    {page: 'image folder name', title: "Title goes here", desc: "description goes here"},
    {page: 'image folder name', title: "Title goes here", desc: "description goes here"}
  ];

//Create labels (Title and Description) based on [page].astro
   return labels.map((label) => {
    return {
      params: { id: label.page },
      props: { title: label.title, desc: label.desc }
    };
  });


// Get all collection folder paths: 'src/images/[collection]'
  const collections: string[] = fg.sync("src/images/*", {
    onlyDirectories: true,
  });

// Create a new route for every collection
  return collections.map((collection) => {
    return {
      params: { collection: collection.split("/").pop() },
      props: {
        images: fg.sync(`${collection}/**/*.{png,jpg}`).map((img) => img.replace("", "/")),
      },
    };
  });
}

export interface Props {
  images: string[];
}

const { collection } = Astro.params;
const { label } = Astro.params
const { images, title, desc } = Astro.props;
---
<div>
  <section>
      {title}
      {desc}
  </section>
  <section>
    {
      images.map((img) => (
        <img src={img} loading="lazy"  />
      ))
    }
  </section>
</div>
```

Obviously, I've made it so sloppy, and I knew this is not the correct way to do this. Clearly, getStaticPaths() will not allow two returns of .map() in the same function. Unless I am missing something?

As much as I've tried to find solutions, I have looked into Astro docs, attempted to find some tips, examples, or tricks. I am not having any luck.

So I was hoping I could get some help finding solutions and getting a better understanding of how to use getStaticPaths() to collect multiple images and data (title and description) into a single page following a routing path. Unless there is another way to do this? What would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `return` statement exits a function immediately, if that's not clear.

Comment: @pointy, "return statement ends the function immediately" care to elaborate?  On what basis? improper nesting closing? please explain

Comment: When execution hits a `return`, the enclosing function is finished. The value of the `return` expression is the returned value to the calling environment. Nothing else in the function happens.

Comment: Note that `return` can only appear in a function. It doesn't have to do with nesting inside local blocks in the function (loops, conditionals, whatever). Now, when a function is nested inside another function, the `return` is only for the most closely associated function; you can't return from more than one function at a time.

Comment: Now I see, this make sense. Thank you for taking time to explain.

Comment: @sirrus do you still need help with something? I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. Only a single page? Then why do you need `getStaticPaths` at all?

Comment: @mb21 - To be clear (i'll try my best}...
I'm creating dynamic routing. The single page will retrieve multiple image files based on the category, determined by the folder name matching the route path. To achieve this, Astro JS requires the `getStaticPaths` function. To clarify, let's consider the home page. Clicking on the Apple link will lead to another page (single page) that displays all Apple images... (Con't)

Comment: (con't)...Similarly, clicking on the Banana link will redirect to the same single page, pulling out all Banana images this time. While I've succeeded with the image part, I've encountered challenges with titles and descriptions based on the category" Yes I might need some help resolve on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, [`Astro.glob` and `import.meta.glob()` don't work if the path contains dynamic parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126196/dynamically-import-all-images-from-a-folder-in-astro) like the name of something in a collection. But the following works:

### Create a collection

Start the `fruit` [content collection](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/) by placing the following in `src/content/fruit/apple.yaml`

```yaml
title: 'Apple'
description: 'Appples are awesome.'
images:
  - src: './apple-1.jpg'
    alt: 'image one desc'
  - src: './apple-2.jpg'
    alt: 'image two desc'
```

Don't forget to add the image files, e.g. `src/content/fruit/apple-1.jpg`

Describe your collection for schema validation and image handling by placing the following in `src/content/config.ts`:

```
import { defineCollection, z } from "astro:content";

// from https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#images-in-content-collections
const fruitCollection = defineCollection({
  schema: ({ image }) => z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    description: z.string(),
    images: z.array( z.object({
      src: image(),
      alt: z.string(),
    })),
  }),
});

export const collections = {
  fruit: fruitCollection,
};
```

### Generate the pages using getStaticPaths

Have Astro generate the pages by placing the following in `src/pages/[...slug].astro`:

```
---
import { Image } from "astro:assets";
import { getCollection } from 'astro:content';


// from https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorials/add-content-collections/#generate-pages-from-a-collection
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const entries = await getCollection('fruit');
  return entries.map(entry => ({
    params: { slug: entry.id }, props: { entry },
  }));
}

const { entry } = Astro.props;
---
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Astro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{entry.data.title}</h1>
    <p>{entry.data.description}</p>
    {entry.data.images.map(image =>
      <Image src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />)}
  </body>
</html>
```

Visit http://localhost:4321/apple/

Comment: Yes! This alternative approach you shared seems to work a lot better for easy comprehension. However, there's one glitch, and it was an easy fix. The line src: ./apple.jpg (apple.yaml) cannot be used as a string file path. I have replaced it with src: /src/content/fruit/apple.jpg. Presumably, it's a 4.0 thing? Thank you for your contribution and time. Problem solved.

Comment: I forgot to mention this: In the latest Astro, the <Image/> asset seems to require the inclusion of width and height, as mentioned here: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#width-and-height-required-for-public-and-remote-images. Does that mean the width/height variables need to be included in apple.yaml as well?

Comment: @sirrus odd, I got it working on 4.0.6: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ha5lwn (the preview doesn't render the image, but I think that's due to stackblitz). Actually, the `image` function you receive in `schema: ({ image })` should figure out the width/height for you. But perhaps if you had to specify the full path that isn't working for you..?

Comment: I am not sure why **`schema: ({ image })`** isn't detecting the image size. However, I do know that I would get an error if the width and height of the image asset do not have a numerical value implemented. Fortunately, after reading somewhere on Astro Lounge in Discord, I could bypass the page error by adding a value of **`1`** to the width and height of the Image asset and include a CSS/Tailwind class, setting the width and height to **`100%`**. This eliminates error issues, and the image on the page looks perfect even at responsive sizes.